# Scratch Org Limit

Tags: rest-api, scratch-org

When I look at my ActiveScratchOrg Limit via the REST API, it is showing that there are Scratch Orgs in use:

[image]

However, when I query `ActiveScratchOrgs` or `ScratchOrgInfo` I get no results. Why would this be?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you're running the queries on the same org and using the same logic credentials?

Comment: Correct yes, all in Workbench

Comment: I know that there are permissions issues - it used to be that a free license based user (i.e. a Dev Hub user) was able to see limits before using the sfdx CLI command, but that changed at some point. Perhaps this is a similar permissions problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was able to replicate the scenario and you would need to enable 'View All' permission for 'Active Scratch Orgs' object so that when you execute query it returns expected results.

SELECT count() FROM ActiveScratchOrg.

[image]

Thanks,